# Error openSSL appears to lack for elliptic curve cryptography? What's that mean and how to resolve it?

Tags: c++, c, linux, cryptography, openssl

Follow the given step [mention on given below link] to compile Bitcoin code, but getting some error? Please let me know what is the problem? how to resolve this?

```
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch03.html#_btcd
Error
[root@localhost bitcoin-0.10.0rc1]# bitcoind
Error: OpenSSL appears to lack support for elliptic curve cryptography. For more information, visit https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OpenSSL_and_EC_Libraries
Error: Initialization sanity check failed. Bitcoin Core is shutting down.
[root@localhost bitcoin-0.10.0rc1]#
```

Comment: I have a hunch that the URL following "For more information, visit " contains at least some information about this problem.

Comment: *"Please let me know what is the problem... What's that mean and how to resolve it?"* - the page in the error message - en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OpenSSL_and_EC_Libraries - tells you what's wrong and how to work around it. What don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 1):

Your platform (Fedora? RedHat?) ships with an OpenSSL build that doesn't have support for elliptic curve cryptography. You'll have to compile your own build that does or find a package that does and install it.

Comment: I am using Fedora 18. How to compile our own build. Actually I am searching for two days, I have found nothing. Give me some advice to do that. Thanks

Comment: @jww You don't have ECC with the Fedora version of OpenSSL 1.0.1, it's disabled (or parts of it are, depending). See, for example [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=319901) and, more specifically, [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1021898).

Comment: Thanks @David. I was not aware that Fedora disabled them.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So ECC Support was disabled in fedora, How can we enable that? Or is there any other Unix OS version which by default have ecc support. Please let me know?

Comment: RedHat has a bit of an ECC patent paranoia. Older versions of RedHat (and derivatives like Fedora) didn't include ECC at all. Newer versions include ECC, but only a few curves (the bitcoin curve is not among them). Most other linux distributions contain OpenSSL with full ECC support.

Comment: thankyou, I have downloaded Ubuntu 14 and its working perfectly.